# How would you markup (with html tags) groups in patterns without erasing the nongrouped patterns?

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

I am building a single page webapp that gives realtime results for lua-patterns.
I use vue magic and fengari js/lua interop to automatically run a function on the screen every time the text you're matching against or a pattern gets updated. The goal of the function is to highlight the matched text.

The relevant lua code here is the function, and the first thing I thought of is simply gsub.
`string.gsub(text_to_test, pattern, function(m) return "<mark>"..m.."</mark>" end)`
This works perfectly - for patterns that feature no groups. Such as: `%u%l`
Test string: `This is your sandbox` pattern: `%s.` Result: `This<mark> i</mark>s<mark> y</mark>our<mark> s</mark>andbox`
But what if someone wants to test a pattern with a group, like: `%s(.)` (or worse: Multiple groups!)
Same test string, pattern is now: `%s(.)` Result: `This<mark>i</mark>s<mark>y</mark>our<mark>s</mark>andbox`
The way the function works, the character in the group is passed as m, and the returned string replaces the entire pattern `%s(.)`, space and character. That's no good!
However, we know that `"%0"` in gsub represents the entire match and not the different groups - The plan: Inside each entire match, mark up the individualized groups.
`string.gsub(s, p, function(m) local w = "%0" return string.gsub(w, m, function(a) return "<mark>"..a.."</mark>" end) end)`
Test string: `This is your sandbox` pattern: `%s.`  Result: `This%0s%0our%0andbox`

Problem: `%0` can only be referenced if directly in the return string. Also I don't think this would work even if I could reference `%0`.

Desired outcome:
For test string `Quick Brown Fox` and pattern `%s(%u)`
produce `Quick<mark> B</mark>rown<mark> F</mark>ox`

I have no idea what the solution is. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole pattern they give you in parentheses, so it's all the first group, no matter what groups are in it:

```
string.gsub(text_to_test, "("..pattern..")", function(m) return "<mark>"..m.."</mark>" end)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't include a desired outcome in my original question. While this solution keeps the strings in tact, it highlights things left out of the groups. If the string is `hEllo` and the pattern is `%l(%u)`, the outcome should be `h<mark>E</mark>llo`. With your fix it is `<mark>hE</mark>llo` (and, for posterity,  with no fix it is `<mark>E</mark>llo`)

Comment: @Allister I don't see a way to do what you want with just Lua's built-in functions. The problem is that none of them give you indices of the beginning and end of captures (like `find` gives you for the whole match).

Comment: I realize I'll have to move beyond just calling a string method I just don't know what I would do instead. Perhaps the easier option is to just cheese it and show users a list of matches instead of trying to highlight.